# HP UFT 12.51 Sets same "creationTime" property for multiple Chrome Profiles

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser, qtp, hp-uft

I want to test one scenario which involves multiple chrome profiles to be setup, and login on each profile using different users and test one Chat client for our company.

Test scenario steps

Launch Profile 1 - Login to the application under test
Launch profile 2 - Login to application under test
Launch profile 3 - Login to application under test
Start chatting on group conversations.

issue Description

When I login to first profile I am setting CreationTime property for next iteration to +1 expecting UFT to identify the same objects on another profile which is not happening. [When I try to manually identify the object they could be identified in object spy.Also Add in is enabled on all profiles]
What I think of that this issue may be because of some user-data argument of chrome. But could not figure out how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: still looking for some ideas!- Thanks..